# Memory leak check in Real time application

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks

I am developing a project in c++ which is like real-time application continuously monitoring data of all critical devices. I try to use Valgrind to check memory leak in the application but when I try use Valgrind in real time testing it ridiculously slows down my application causing damage to my system performance.

Is there any such method or tool which I can use to do memory leak check in Real time application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some memory analysis tools such as valgrind, Dr. Memory and Intel Inspector uses binary execution engines which means they actually disassemble and then emulate the execution. They also employ a technique called shadow memory which helps them to track all read write accesses. They do this not only for  spotting memory leaks but also buffer overflows, corruptions etc.

However when it comes to only heap based leak finding, capturing calls to heap allocation funtions may be sufficient. This is basically done via a method called hooking.

For Linux :

**1. Heaptrack :** I haven`t used myself yet. But this one uses hooking and claims to be much faster than valgrind :

Its page : http://milianw.de/blog/heaptrack-a-heap-memory-profiler-for-linux

Its CPPCon 2015 Video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myDWLPBiHn0

**2. Address sanitizer :** As you have access to source code and compile it, you can use with both GCC ( 4.8+ ) and Clang. As for GCC search for -fsanitize=leak

**3. GNU LIB C Hooking :** You can also programatically hook GNU Lib C runtimes memory functions. For an example look at here : https://github.com/akhin/cpp_multithreaded_order_matching_engine/blob/master/source/memory/debugging/hook_gnu_libc.h

You can also combine this by using programatic breakpoints. For an example :

https://github.com/akhin/cpp_multithreaded_order_matching_engine/blob/master/source/memory/debugging/hardware_breakpoint.h

I find this approach particularly useful as you can narrow down your search into a range allocation events.

**4. Using a 3rd party allocator :** You can use a 3rd party allocator such as Google`s TCMalloc or Jemalloc in order to find leaks :

https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Use-Case%3A-Leak-Checking

http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/heap_checker.html

Comment: Here is the latest link to Google Perf Tools. https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools
I've used the heap profiler and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at address sanitizer, leak sanitizer and other related tools: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html , http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html

Comment: Note that these are both also available in gcc (4.8 onwards for Address Sanitizer and 4.9 onwards for Leak Sanitizer)